# ASP.NET Core Date/Time Localization

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, format, asp.net-core-localization

I'm implementing localization in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app to support multiple languages in the UI, but I'm running into issues due to the different calendars each culture uses. How do I set Gregorian as the calendar type for all cultures?

Here is my `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var cultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("ar"),
        new CultureInfo("en")
    };

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
        )
    );
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddExpressLocalization<ExpressLocalizationResource, ViewLocalizationResource>(
            ops =>
            {
                ops.ResourcesPath = "LocalizationResources";
                ops.RequestLocalizationOptions = o =>
                {
                    o.SupportedCultures = cultures;
                    o.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
                    o.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                };
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: You can use data type templating to have one date format across your app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822264/datetime-format-debugging/60823150#60823150 is that what youre looking for?

Comment: Not quite. Though I realize now that my problem comes from the fact that the Arabic localization uses a different calendar than the English one. I have updated my question to reflect that. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can change a `CultureInfo`'s calendar through its `DateTimeForm` property. Something like this:

```cs
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { };
var ar = new CultureInfo("ar");
ar.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
ar.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
ar.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
supportedCultures.Add(ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the calendar for a culture.

So for your example the following code would change the "ar" culture to use a gregorian calendar.

```cs
CultureInfo ar = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar");
ar.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

var cultures = new[]
{
    ar,
    new CultureInfo("en")
};
```

Documentation for calendars and cultureinfo

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/working-with-calendars